# How do I make a Word Table of Authorities correctly sort rule numbers?

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents

I'm generating a Table of Authorities in Microsoft word, but it has trouble recognizing that "Crim. R. 3" comes before "Crim. R. 12," so I end up with out-of-order entries in my table, like this:
[image: bad table]
No matter what I do, I can't get it to treat Rule 3 as coming before Rule 12. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word doesn't know how to do this.

The best workaround that will automatically update as you continue to edit the document is to add a leading zero to the citation marker and make it imperceptible.

When you mark a citation, Word adds a bit of code in front of each instance, so it looks like this when you can see all the markup:

`{ TA \l "Crim. R. 3" \s "Crim. R. 3" \c 9 }`

You want Word to think there's a leading zero in front of the there ("Crim. R. 03"), but you don't want to see it throughout your document. So go ahead and mark all the instances of Crim. R. 3 the normal way, but then go into the markup and add as many leading zeroes as you need, so it looks like this:

`{ TA \l "Crim. R. 03" \s "Crim. R. 03" \c 9 }`

The Table of Authorities will now sort the rule in the correct order, but it will show up looking like this:
[image]
I think that still doesn't look great, so I go one step further: Inside those citations, I reformat he leading zeroes so they're basically invisible. When Word builds the TOA, it will capture most of the formatting from inside the code, so I reformat the zero (but not the three):

1. Change it to the smallest font you can find. On my machine, it's ZWAdobeF.
2. Change the size to 1 point.
3. Change the font color to white.
4. Drop it into subscript.

Once you've done that, you've locked the leading zero into the code but made it virtually invisible, and it looks like this: [image]
Now Word can use it to properly sort the entry, but the workaround is imperceptible to the naked eye, assuming you're not making a billboard out of this.

Answer (score 1):

for the two-digit citations that you want to sort BENEATH the single digit citations, use the HARD SPACE in the TA codes (but not necessarily in the text entry) (Cntrl-Shift-Spacebar) instead of the regular space.  The hard spaces sorts after the regular space

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple manipulations you can do to fix the problem:

- Add a space before the "3"
- Sort manually
  (ensure that you do not update fields after you have made the changes manually):

  - Cut and paste the citations properly
  - Highlight the citations and use the Sort option in the pane
    *Table Tool > Layout*.